# Can I have a UISearchBar be its own .inputAccessoryView?

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, inputaccessoryview

I need simple text input to aid in data filtering.  Ideally I'd like to keep a strong reference to a UISearchBar, and when the user taps "Search", then this searchBar would becomeFirstResponder() and I would set

`self.searchBar.inputAccessoryView = self.searchBar`

But that doesn't seem to work.  The .searchBar is generally not in the view controller's view hierarchy, and is something I would just hope to attach to the keyboard.

Otherwise I'll think of another approach.  Ultimately I'm just trying to have text input that I can see while editing, and that should be attached to the toolbar.  Ideally with an .inputAccessoryView so I don't have to bother with keyboard notifications / animations

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use the search bar both for triggering a keyboard and for showing the search term entered by the user, but do not want to always have the search bar on-screen but have it activated via a "Search" button.

That's not possible with a single `UISearchBar`, but you can just use two of them:

- Add one as subview to your view controller and hide it (bar1), and use the second as `inputAccessoryView` (bar2); you should become delegate of both search bars.
- When the user presses the "Search" button make bar1 become first responder, handle its events via the delegate protocol, and update the bar2 accordingly.
- Prevent the user from directly entering text in bar2 by blocking it
  with the `shouldChangeTextIn` delegate method. Other events that are
  received in bar2 could be forwarded to bar1 where this makes sense for you.

To get you started, here's some code for the basic setup (which would go in e.g. `viewDidLoad`):

```
self.dummySearchBar = UISearchBar()
dummySearchBar.isHidden = true
dummySearchBar.delegate = self

self.visibleSearchBar = UISearchBar()
visibleSearchBar.delegate = self
dummySearchBar.inputAccessoryView = visibleSearchBar
```

Then, in your "Search" button handler, let the keyboard with the attached search bar appear like this:

```
dummySearchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Note: I have a similar setup in a project but for simplicity I use  `UITextField`s instead of `UISearchBar`s; still, I think the basic approach should work with `UISearchBar`s as well.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm able to cook up my own solution, but of course, no matter what, I don't think the user can use long-press (text editing?)  Anyway, I'm taking another approach for now.  Thanks for confirming what I suspected.

Answer (score 0):

add toolBar to searchBar

```
searchBar.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

hide keyboard

```
searchBar.endEditing(true)
```